# Cannot find module 'puppeteer'

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

In a AWS Lambda/NodeJS runtime, I'm attempting to import from an absolute path (`/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer`).

Source runs fine locally but, once bundled with Webpack/serverless-webpack and run in AWS Lambda, `require('puppeteer')` results in:

```
{"errorMessage":"Cannot find module 'puppeteer'","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["webpackMissingModule (/var/task/src/render/handler.js:643:89)","/var/task/src/render/handler.js:643:173","next (native)","step (/var/task/src/render/handler.js:608:191)","/var/task/src/render/handler.js:608:361"]}
```

I've checked:

- AWS Lambda Layer is mounted at `/opt`.
- The path `/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer` does exist.
- `NODE_PATH` correctly includes `/opt/nodejs/node_modules`

Comment: It would actually be more appropriate to include `puppeteer-core` and use `puppeteer` as a dev-dependency, then pass a executable path based off your environment to `browser.launch()`.  Puppeteer-core is without chromium bundled, so you're safe to import and use it.  The base puppeteer package will include chromium for local development, but won't get bundled due to being a dev dependency.

Answer (score 23):

You have to install your module with `save` flag before uploading your zip to Amazon :

```
npm i puppeteer --save
```

Comment: In this particular case, it turns out that `--save-dev` was more appropriate — but got me thinking in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Yes you should adjust my answer (I don't know if you use puppeteer just for dev) ; I'm just giving you a hint happy coding

Answer (score 14):

`npm i --save puppeteer` results in a too big package. (Max 50MB for Lambdas.)

So, instead, puppeteer was installed with `npm i --save-dev puppeteer --ignore-scripts`. (Ignore scripts to prevent Chromium from being installed.) The `serverless-webpack` plugin had to be told to ignore puppeteer in its packaging. (Otherwise puppeteer would bloat the package.)

The puppeteer module was put in a Layer (in the folder structure mentioned in the question) and `require('puppeteer')` now works.

Comment: Ho to make it works on global scope, I tried `sudo npm install puppeteer -g` but still got same error message.

Comment: nicely said, we can exclude the Chromium which could not be needed

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **stencil.js** it gives a very similar error. Try updating the stencil core version to at least `"@stencil/core": "^1.15.0"`

In your shell prompt try

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script by forcing the environment variable $NODE_PATH. Such as:

```
NODE_PATH=/opt/nodejs/node_modules /path/to/bin/node your-file.js
```

For a specific reason I had to build from source a version of node without affecting the currently installation and this workaround worked for me.

I've got to this solution based on the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656431/using-node-modules-folder-for-custom-modules).

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i puppeteer --save
```

You have to install your module with save flag before uploading your zip